# VB LINQ to SQL as variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, variables, datacontext

I have searched everywhere and cannot find the answer. Every example either has a datagridview  or stops at Select. I need to store the DataContext result as a variable in VB. In a previous bit of code I'm populating the ComobBox with a dropdown list of customer names. Then when the user selects a customer name from the Combbox list I want to:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim dbmanex As New Manex_LINQDataContext
Dim dbPhone = From c In dbmanex.CUSTOMERs
Where c.CUSTNAME = Me.ComboBox1.Text
Select c.PHONE
Me.PhoneTextBox.Text = dbPhone
End Sub
```

The PhoneTextBox.Text is just blank. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

SOLVED by Kirill Bestemyanov:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim dbmanex As New Manex_LINQDataContext
Dim dbPhone = From c In dbmanex.CUSTOMERs
Select c.PHONE
Me.PhoneTextBox.Text = dbPhone.Single()
End Sub
```

Comment: Since the ComboBox is populated from the DataContext, it's probably safe to assume that the customer exists in the context.  However, I think it's important to note that if 0 or 2 or more results are returned by the query, calling `Single()` will throw an exception.  I generally prefer to use `SingleOrDefault()`, as that will return the default value for the type if 0 matches are found (although it will throw an exception if 2 or more are found).

Comment: It depends on requirements. I prefer that application throw exception but do not save wrong data to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should materialize your query.

```
Me.PhoneTextBox.Text=dbPhone.Single();
```

When you call Single() your query will call db and get value from it.

Comment: SOLVED! YES! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I know a hundred other people will thank you for that super simple answer too. Thank you for taking the time.